# Query select an associate record value of each record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to run a query(Oracle) that select all employee records with Deptment_ID=NBS
  and also brings his/her manager's name from another record, each department has many units and each has a manager(in every record there are two columns repTo and J_NBR. The manager name comes from REPTO= J_NBR )
example:

**First**        **Last** ... **Dept_ID**       **REPTO**                  **J_NBR**
MIke                 SAB            NBS           400          200
...

Sarah      Wood         NBs            600           400

Chris    JONSON         NBS         800                          600
...

Here Mike's manager is SaraH Mike's REPTO= Sarah' J_NBR

The Select query results would be(there is not a column name as manager in database):

First     Last ...     Deptment_ID         REPTO    J_NBR     Manager

MIke       SAB  ...        NBS               400           200            Sarah

Sarah    Wood            NBs                             600                         400            Chris 
..

How would be the SQL.

Thank,
MK

Comment: Should be a simple self-join **SELECT * FROM employee emp JOIN employee mgr ON emp.REPTO = mgr.J_NBR**

Comment: What did you try so far? You need to join the employee table with itself

Comment: I used SELECT  * FROM employee emp LEFT JOIN employee mgr ON emp.REPTO = mgr.J_NBR where mgr.depid='MN' and mgr.depid='MN' but i can not get the head of department name because he has another REPTO number which would be a director has another depid. How can get the head of department name?